# Why does java de/serialization succeed even between incompatible object versions?

Tags: java, serialization, late-binding

In a client-server setup, I modified the class definition of an object sent by the server and expected to crash on the client side (the client jar has not been updated to reflect these changes).

It doesn't crash, however.

Note: the way objects are used by the client, might avoid the crash. The client never casts the Object that is deserialized, and never uses fields that were removed. The object is only used from Python scripts via Jython, which probably employs some late-binding mechanism (reflection?) when using fields of the object, therefore making things possible. This also assumes that serialization includes class' signature, which is true (mentioned by documentation of ObjectOutputStream).

Also to note: we never change the serialVersionUid.

DOes my reasoning seem correct?

Answer (score 3):

Serialization will use class signature to generate versioning only when you dont provide the serialVersionUID, since you are providing one, class signature wont be used.

Since its not changing it assumes both are compatible and carries out the default behavior

Comment: Ok, so I'm using a SerialVersionUID that stays always =1. You are saying that class signature is "not used". How, then, is java able to pull from a stream, an object whose class is unknown?

Answer (score 1):

Well if you're using `serialVersionUID` in your class then it's up to you to change it.

Otherwise java will rely upon reflection to throw an exception if there were any changes.

Comment: In my case I'm deserializing into a class that has an extra field (from a stream that doesn't provide it). My serialVersionUID's are equal. No exception is thrown, although according to the specification, this should be a breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting a field isn't an incompatible change, as long as the serialVersionUIDs match. See the Object Versioning chapter of the Object Serialization Specification.